# In the RBC model, why is household's problem dynamic?

Tags: macroeconomics, dynamic-optimization, capital, rbc

Why is capital assumed to be a good accumulated in the current period t but being used in t+1? I think my interpretation is wrong here. I understand that households problem is dynamic because of this capital component but a more elaborate explanation will really help me understand it.

Comment: I failed to mention the expectation and discount factor here that makes the household problem dynamic as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Damien. The introduction of time allows for more realistic economic behaviour (i.e. savings and investment), that would not otherwise happen if time did not exist. In many ways, introducing time into a model is a first-approximation at introducing uncertainty.